# Django template system and several month_list

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

What is the best way to render a monthly stat on a template page ?

I've started with lists originally for template ease but after switching to dictionaries i've been able to do the same things more smoothly. Trouble is that a dictionary is, by definition, not sorted. Then if i iteritems() the dictionary i won't get a clean result but something more like

```
('Feb', 'Dec', 'Oct' ...)
```

Should i change my dictionnary into a list of tuple before processing to the template or is there a way to render thoses data with advanced knowledge of template django's template system ?

My dictionary is constructed like that :

```
{'mnth_subscription': {'cummu_sbcr_mthl': {'Mar': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Aug': 0, 'Sep': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'Jun': 0, 'Jul': 0, 'Jan': 0, 'May': 0, 'Nov': 2221, 'Dec': 2221, 'Oct': 2221}, 'monthly_perc': {'Mar': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Aug': 0, 'Sep': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'Jun': 0, 'Jul': 0, 'Jan': 0, 'May': 0, 'Nov': -100, 'Dec': 0, 'Oct': 100}, 'cummu_sbcr_perc': {'Mar': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Aug': 0, 'Sep': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'Jun': 0, 'Jul': 0, 'Jan': 0, 'May': 0, 'Nov': 100, 'Dec': 100, 'Oct': 100}, 'monthly_subscription': {'Mar': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Aug': 0, 'Sep': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'Jun': 0, 'Jul': 0, 'Jan': 0, 'May': 0, 'Nov': 0, 'Dec': 0, 'Oct': 2221}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make each information as ordered list of dict. So information of `Jan` is 0th element and so forth. Example

```
{ 'cummu_sbcr_mthl': [ {'Mar', 0}, {'Feb': 0} ..., {'Dec': 0} ],
   'monthly_perc': [ .... ],
}
```

Or another approach:

Create list of dicts. For example, create the list as below.

```
month_subscription =  [ 
        { 'month': 'Mar', 'mindex': 3, 'cummu_sbcr_mnthl': 0, 'monthly_per': 0, 
          'cummu_sbcr_perc': 0, 'monthly_subscription': 0
        },
        ...
        { 'month': 'Oct', 'mindex': 10, 'cummu_sbcr_mnthl': 2221, 'monthly_per': 100, 
          'cummu_sbcr_perc': 100, 'monthly_subscription': 2221
        },
     ]
```

You may want to remove `'mindex'` if not required.

Comment: That's one structure i though about but i figured out that repetition of "kind" of information is even worse than just month repetition. The trouble is that i need to be able to iterate something like that in template : cummy_sbcr_perc : Jan :10, Feb, 23 etc...

Comment: You need to get ordered list, but dict cannot give you that. Check first part in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)? Behaves pretty much the same as dict, just be a bit careful with the constructor: don't pass it a dict (since that dict will be unordered before passed to the OrderedDict constructor).